# ASP.NET MVC Creating different models from the same stored procedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, models

Is it possible to create different models from the same stored procedure that return completely different sets of data based upon parameters? I would be obviously creating a model using the database-first approach.

Comment: I think you can only bind 1 complex type object to a stored procedure

Comment: Yes of course, using SqlDataReader https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx - but this has nothing to do with MVC.

Comment: True. But I apologize, I was referring to going through the Entity Data Model Wizard. Once it spits out the Model for you after you've set the sproc at the source, you can go into to the edit-function import screen and click "Get Column Information" button, but if you have multuiple IF statements based on a parameter that return different datasets, there's no easy way to get the columns/types. You would think they'd add something into this screen to allow you to add a parameter before getting this column information